# What is an OS Image and VM image , In short I would need to understand in more visual and laymen terms?

Tags: operating-system, virtual-machine, docker-swarm

I am trying to understand, what is an OS image and VM image and how they are different?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An *OS Image* commonly refers to a collection of the programs and data files needed to make an *operating system* functional.  That is a minimal definition; but an *image* needn't be minimal.

A *Virtual Machine* image commonly refers to all of the *state*: memory, device registers, etc... of a *virtual machine*.   In contrast to an *OS Image*, a *Virtual Machine* can be restarted after halting; whereas an *OS Image* restarts from the beginning.   A *system image* commonly refers to the equivalent of a *virtual machine image* for a real hardware machine.

Why do these terms exist?   When an operating system starts, there is little to no functioning system software on the target machine; so the first level of starting (bootstrapping) is to put some *lump* of something into RAM, and start executing it.  That *lump* might be an operating system, or may be a small intermediate system that will then load the actual operating system (or load yet another boot loader).  An example is *grub* or *u-boot*.

An intermediary system may be more functional than to just *load a lump and jump*.  It might understand file systems, and be able to parse device database; thus construct an appropriate OS image for the target hardware on the fly.  The division of labour is a compromise chosen by the system designer.

Intel based systems add an incredibly complex intermediary into all of this with a system called ACPI which sits underneath the Extensible Firmware Interface.  The A in *ACPI* stands for Advanced, I suppose *new and improved* was too transparent.